# How do I find the cause for my program crashing Linux?

Tags: linux, crash, gpu, opengl

I am developping an OpenGL graphics program in Arch Linux. Everything was working fine, except I recently attempted to render the Sponza scene.

The program launches and runs fine, however my GPU starts making a screeching noise (I imagine it's the fans turning too quickly) and after about a minute the entire system crashes and reboots.

Checking VRAM shows that there is still at leas 4GB of VRAM available when the program crashes, so I don't think this is a running out of memory problem.

The other potential problem I can think off is my power supply running out of power, however I have a 750B evga power supply and my GPU is only consuming 119W out of 200W at the time of the crash (inspected with nvidia-smi).

Given that the system reboots when the error happens I am not sure which log to inspect to determine the caus eof the error.

Comment: First of all, deal with overheating of your GPU.

Comment: The last reported temperature of the GPU is 50 C, which is within normal parameters accoridng to the spec

Comment: You wrote that fans are turning too fast and making noise. That's overheating. Whatever is reporting GPU temperature is out to lunch, as most sensor programs under *NIX are. Unless of course you've done lots of research and adjusted constants using an external thermometer.

Comment: The other reason why it's unlikely to be overheating, is because closing the program just before the expected crash time (about a minute) prevents rebooting

Comment: Then how do you explain high fan RPMs? The built in sensor in the GPU cannot be tricked - it's overheating. If you close the program, you avoid overheating the GPU. I develop in OpenCL and have learned from experience that Linux sensor monitoring lies 99% of the time.

Comment: Is there a check to be 100% certian this is the cause?

Comment: Run your program in a VM under Windows and use HWMonitor or your card vendor's thermal monitoring tool (like Saphire's TriXX which I use now), whichever is better. Or port to Windows and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Arch Linux, you can try `journalctl -k -b -1` this should show all kernel logs from the last boot.

Also, I think this might be a problem with your PSU. You mentioned you have 4GB VRAM, judging from that, you have a powerful system, and 200W is nowhere near enough for that.

Comment: My PSU is a 750B evga, the 200W is the maximum load of the GPU

Comment: Oh, my mistake here. In this case, check journalctl, since this is likely a software problem.

Comment: Power consumption by GPUs is highly overrated. Reality is different. I've tested many systems using a digital power meter, and all w/o exception used a fraction of "required" Watts.